# How to replace Collada-imported textures with ShaderMaterial ones in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js, collada

Is there a way to replace all textures in a simple 3D model imported via Collada loader in the Three.js library?

What I'd like to accomplish is to apply colour, specular and normal maps to the model via ShaderMaterial by pointing to new files with the model's material names but added "-color", "-normal" and "-spec" wording:

"brochureFrontCover" -> "brochureFrontCover-color.jpg", "brochureFrontCover-normal.jpg", "brochureFrontCover-spec.jpg"

If any good soul could show me how such function should look, I'd be very grateful.

The script: 
http://dev.printhouse.co.uk/uv-simulator/j/Brochure.js

Collada model: 
http://dev.printhouse.co.uk/uv-simulator/m/Brochure.dae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be something like this:

```
THREE.SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy( dae, function ( child ) {

    if ( child.material ) {

        var shader = THREE.ShaderUtils.lib[ "normal" ];
        var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( shader.uniforms );

        uniforms[ "tDiffuse" ].texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( child.material.name + "-color.jpg" );
        uniforms[ "tNormal" ].texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( child.material.name + "-normal.jpg" );
        uniforms[ "tSpecular" ].texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( child.material.name + "-spec.jpg" );

        uniforms[ "enableDiffuse" ].value = true;
        uniforms[ "enableSpecular" ].value = true;

        child.geometry.computeTangents();

        child.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
            uniforms: uniforms,
            vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
            fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
            lights: true
        } );

    }

} );
```

[This example](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_normalmap2.html) should be a good reference if you need to tweak uniforms.

Comment: Thanks mrdoob! I've updated the script and am getting `GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawXXX: attempt to access out of range vertices` error. Should `dae` argument call any specific level in the model's hierarchy (I set it to `dae = collada.scene;`)?

Comment: Oh uh! Well, start just by doing `child.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { wireframe: true } );` to see if at least that works...

Comment: Yep, that shows a nice wireframed model. So, what do you think?

Comment: Could anyone update me if this is a bug in the library or if there's another way of doing it? Many thanks!

Comment: So, having `child.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { wireframe: true } );` working... at which point do you start to get problems?

Comment: As soon as I switch to `child.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(...)`. I can see all the images loading properly in the console, the model just doesn't show up and I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: thanks for helping with this. See [example](http://dev.printhouse.co.uk/uv-simulator/brochure.html) returning the error.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I think you're just missing             `geometry.computeTangents()`. I've updated my answer.